# HotswapAgent plugins

Tags: hotswap, dcevm

I am going to develop custom HotswapAgent plugin, but I don't know where it should be deployed.
All standard plugins are bundled within agent jar file. Is there any directory where should I put my plugin jar file or do I have to embed it in the agent jar file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is hotswap-agent.properties file, which allows to specify pluginPackages property, which instructs hotswap-agent to load specific packages and seek for @Plugin annotated classes.

However I encountered problem with classloader hierarchy order, which causes that Plugin class cannot be found from hotswap-agent classloader.

There is an StackOwerflow question for that: [HotSwapAgent plugin - plugin class not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28405905/hotswapagent-plugin-plugin-class-not-found)